# Java Bean Conditional Validation

Tags: java, spring, javabeans, bean-validation

I have a class with two attributes. I want to use Java Bean Validation but ran with one problem on how to approach?

```
class ProductRequest {

   private String quantityType;
   private double quantityValue;

   //getters and setters
}
```

I want to use Java Bean Validation based on below condition.
If "quantityType" is equals to "foo", limit "quantityValue" to maximum size of 5
else "quantityType" is equals to "bar", limit "quantityValue" to maximum size of 3.

What will be the best way to approach in this scenario?

Comment: you need a custom validator https://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator

Comment: Thanks Jayesh for your comments, I am trying to implement without custom validation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
import javax.validation.constraints.AssertTrue;


@AssertTrue
public boolean isBothFieldsValid() {
    if (quantityType.equals("foo")) {
        return quantityValue < 5;
    } else if (quantityType.equals("bar")) {
        return quantityValue < 3;
    }
    return false;
}
```

EDIT:

Addressing question from comment. You can try using two methods at once:

```
@AssertTrue(message = "quantity should be below 5 for foo")
public boolean isQuantityValidForFoo() {
    if (quantityType.equals("foo")) {
        return quantityValue < 5;
    }
    return true;
}

@AssertTrue(message = "quantity should be below 3 for bar")
public boolean isQuantityValidForBar() {
    if (quantityType.equals("bar")) {
        return quantityValue < 3;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: Just to be sure Krystian, I need to add this method on the same model class right? And how will it be triggered for input validation ?

Comment: Yes, add it to ProductRequest class. I assumed you're already using some validation annotation like '@NotNull' and this one works exactly the same. It works as a getter to new field `@AssertTrue private boolean bothFieldsValid;`. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6283726/jsf-jsr-303-bean-validation-why-on-getter-and-not-setter

Comment: Thanks, it worked! Do you have any idea of setting different message for false condition of @AssertTrue based on these condition ? i.e if equals to "foo" and quantity >= 5 , @AssertTrue(message = "quantity should be below 5 for foo") and if equals to "bar" and quantity >= 3 then @AssertTrue(message = "quantity should be below 3 for bar") ?

Comment: Perfect! This is way I was looking for. Thanks, Krystian.